# Applescripting ODBC

Tags: applescript, database

Is it possible to interact with an ODBC connection within AppleScript?  Or must one break out into another process (e.g. Python, Perl, etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AppleScript has very few built-in capabilities, and in particular, no built-in functions to talk to databases, either via ODBC or any other protocol.

What is does provide you is a way to control *applications* that have that ability, or cut out to system scripts that also have the ability as you suggested in your question.